# List of cached objects (including primary/secondary location) by key in AppFabric cache

Tags: caching, high-availability, appfabric

I have AppFabric installed and working great caching my ASP.Net Sessions.  I have 3 W2k8 Enterprise servers as my cache hosts.  I created my cache with the Secondaries=1 option.  I'm trying to test the High Availability option.  In order to do this, I would like to login to my website, find the cache server that has my session and unplug it from the network (simulating a server crash).  If I can still work as a logged in user, I can prove that High Availability is working and the secondary copy of my session was promoted.

How can I see a list of the objects in the cache and where the primary/secondary objects "live"?

Answer (score 2):

The `get-cache` [Powershell command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718177.aspx#cachehost) can show you your caches running in a cluster, and where their objects (and regions) are located.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to get all cache objects. Be careful though because depending on your cache size it can take a significant amount of time to dump all cache objects:

```
foreach (var regionName in cache.GetSystemRegions())
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> cacheItem in cache.GetObjectsInRegion(regionName))
    {
        // TODO: process cacheItem.Key and cacheItem.Value
    }
}
```